# select2 changing positon of drop down list

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-select2

I have used select2 as follows

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>          
<script type="text/javascript" src="select2.js"></script>          

 <link href="select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#e1").select2();
    });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

</br>
<input type="hidden" id="1234">
<select multiple id="e1" style="width:300px">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
        <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
        <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>

        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>

</body>
</html>
```

Now in output if after selecting one item i want dropdown list to appear after that selected work what should i make changes in code..please help..

Comment: Hi, I have created a jsFiddle, with your code, link: http://jsfiddle.net/tiagoajacobi/t5whj/, could you explain better what are you trying to do? Maybe with an Image.